# using SUM on foreign view's keys grouped on multiple key/values?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I had a [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260120/use-sum-on-foreign-keys-where-it-matches-rows-id?noredirect=1#comment513241_260120) on executing SUM on rows from one table and inserting them in a column on another table where the calculated rows shared id with a row in the new table.

The solution worked very well for that instance. However, I have a similar situation in which that query no longer works.

I have this TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE buildings (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    name character varying(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    document jsonb
);
```

then this VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW v_rooms AS  
SELECT buildings.id AS building_id,
    buildings.name AS building_name,
    jsonb_array_elements( document -> 'levels' ) -> 'meta' ->> 'level_number' AS level_number,
    ((jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(buildings.document -> 'levels'::text) -> 'rooms'::text) -> 'meta'::text) ->> 'sqft'::text)::numeric AS sqft
FROM buildings
GROUP BY buildings.id;
```

finally in this VIEW:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_levels AS
SELECT
  buildings.id AS building_id,
  buildings.name AS building_name,
  jsonb_array_elements( document -> 'levels' ) -> 'meta' ->> 'level_number' AS number,
  sqft
FROM buildings
```

I want the COLUMN 'sqft' to be the SUM of all rows in v_rooms where v_rooms.building_id = v_levels.building_id AND v_rooms.level_number = v_levels.number.

I tried this VIEW definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_levels AS
SELECT
  buildings.id AS building_id,
  buildings.name AS building_name,
  jsonb_array_elements( document -> 'levels' ) -> 'meta' ->> 'level_number' AS number,
  sqft
FROM buildings
JOIN (
  SELECT building_id, level_number, sum(sqft) as sqft
  FROM v_rooms
  GROUP BY ( v_rooms.building_id, v_rooms.level_number )
) v_rooms ON ( v_rooms.building_id = buildings.id and v_rooms.level_number = level_number );
```

but I get duplicates, one row for the matching building_id and then again every time level number matches. which is an issue because level number is not unique to the table and only to the building.

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1248bb0352fb1450eef43f95b0046c57)

Comment: @McNets 
I edited error of  no level_number column on post. the error you're getting is the lack of JOIN which I have in the second definition for v_levels. 

I've made [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1248bb0352fb1450eef43f95b0046c57) fiddle.

You can see, I get four results for v_levels. When I want two. One for each levels and total sqft calc for the rooms nested within them in the json.

Comment: Postgres 11.6 is my version btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You barely got it, once you have unnested the arrays you can simply aggregate the result by building.id, name and level in this way:

```
WITH ct AS
(
  SELECT 
    buildings.id AS building_id
    ,buildings.name AS building_name
    ,jsonb_array_elements( document -> 'levels' ) -> 'meta' ->> 'level_number' AS level_number
    ,((jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(buildings.document->'levels')->'rooms')->'meta')->>'sqft')::numeric AS sqft
  FROM 
    buildings
)
SELECT
    building_id, building_name, level_number,
    SUM(sqft) AS sqft
FROM
    ct
GROUP BY
    building_id, building_name, level_number;
```

> ```
> building_id | building_name | level_number | sqft
> ----------: | :------------ | :----------- | ---:
>           1 | my blding     | 0            | 1300
>           1 | my blding     | 1            | 1800
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3dfe64fc7217a6834244cfc9e9419133)*

Comment: Nice, so we can unnest the json for rooms in a single query. I didn't know that SELECT can handle varying array lengths like 'levels' and 'rooms'. Thanks a lot @McNets